# getting the return value of Future Function in Flutter without Stateless/Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-future

I just want to return the value of each condition and use it as the value of the function.

Here is my code for it.

```
var getStuff = chechIfExisting();

chechIfExisting() async {
  var isExisting = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('merchants')
      .doc(userUid)
      .get();
  if (isExisting.exists) {
    return 'exists';
  }
  if (!isExisting.exists) {
    return 'nope';
  } else {
    return 'error';
  }
}
```

and I am not using any **Stateless and Stateful Widget** since this file contains only the widgets such as appbar/mydrawer. I wanted to use the 'getStuff' variable in a if statement under the myDrawer Widget, since I want to dynamically check if the the data that I am fetching is existing or not.

```
myDrawer(BuildContext context) {
print('getStuff');
// only prints 'Instance of 'Future<String>' and does not return the value.
}
```

I want to be able to use the 'getStuff' variable as

```
myDrawer(BuildContext context) {
if(getStuff == 'exists'){
 // code here
}
```

Any helps/ideas on how to solve this are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this  line:

```
var getStuff = chechIfExisting();
```

You're not waiting for the method to finishes executing, since it's a `Future`, not using either `await`/`async` or `then` to resolve values after the `Future` finishes will get you that `getStuff()` is a type of `Instance of 'Future<String>`, before the running of the `myDrawer` function, you need either to:

```
var getStuff = await chechIfExisting(); // inside an async method
```

or:

```
chechIfExisting().then((resolvedValue) {
  getStuff = resolvedValue;
 });
```

then you can run the `myDrawer` method and get it working fine

Comment: Great explanation, however I used the second one with ``.then()``. That worked well.